# device is not defined error in PhoneGap Push Notification

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification

I am using PhoneGap for developing android app. I am stuck while implementing **push notification** plugin, i am getting "device is not defined" error when i run code.

I am using  https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin library for this work.

Please help me out. Thanks

Comment: May be it has a dependency on device plugin. Suggestion: install the device plugin, http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#Device check if the error is gone. If it doesn't work, you can remove the device plugin

Comment: thanks. i installed device plugin and "device is not defined" error went but now "[ERROR] Error initializing Cordova: Class not found" error is coming. Sorry i am new with Android, so your help is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to include the plugin device. Otherwise your call to "device.platform" will trigger an error!